# Conversion of Mysql date format (DD-MM-YYYY TO YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: mysql

I have three column mysql table
ID (int)
Date (Varchar) (data in dd-mm-yyyy)
Logdate (Date) (Currently empty)

Is there any query which can fetch date and update the Logdate with mysql date format (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: Yes [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the string to a `Date` value. You have to specify the format of the date string you provided. In your case it would be `'%d-%m-%Y'`. For testing purposes you can run the following queries to check if it works:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN Dummy;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| oldDate | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| logdate | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Dummy;
+------+------------+------------+
| ID   | oldDate    | logdate    |
+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | 24-12-2019 | 2000-01-01 |
|    1 | 04-09-2017 | 2000-01-01 |
|    1 | 21-02-2019 | 2000-01-01 |
+------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT oldDate, STR_TO_DATE(oldDate, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM Dummy;
+------------+----------------------------------+
| oldDate    | STR_TO_DATE(oldDate, '%d-%m-%Y') |
+------------+----------------------------------+
| 24-12-2019 | 2019-12-24                       |
| 04-09-2017 | 2017-09-04                       |
| 21-02-2019 | 2019-02-21                       |
+------------+----------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can then run an `UPDATE` query to update the values in the `logdate` column.

```
mysql> UPDATE Dummy SET logdate = STR_TO_DATE(oldDate, '%d-%m-%Y');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM Dummy;
+------+------------+------------+
| ID   | oldDate    | logdate    |
+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | 24-12-2019 | 2019-12-24 |
|    1 | 04-09-2017 | 2017-09-04 |
|    1 | 21-02-2019 | 2019-02-21 |
+------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do manual positioning from the query. Here is on example:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',RIGHT(date,4),MID(date,4,2),LEFT(date,2)) as Newdate FROM table;
```

Then with that you can construct your update query as following:

```
UPDATE table SET Logdate = CONCAT_WS('-',RIGHT(date,4),MID(date,4,2),LEFT(date,2));
```

**EDITED:**
I removed my first comment about `STR_TO_DATE` because after testing, it proved to be usable as pointed out in @Progman answer.